# Displaying top level category name in view | ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have one `blog_categories` table with `sub_categories` based on a `parent_id` value that points to the main category's `.id` that is above the subcategory. Main categories have a `parent_id` of `NULL`. This is all done through self-referential relations.

How do I display the name of the current `sub_category` and parent `blog_category` in the blog_categories.show view based on the `/blog_categories/#`?

> For example;
>
> - **"News"** has `.id` 1 and `parent_id` `NULL` since it's the main category.
> - **"Good"** has `.id` 2 and `parent_id` `1` since it belongs to the category with an `.id` of 1.
> - **"Bad"** has `.id` 3 and `parent_id` `1` since it belongs to the category with an `.id` of 1.
>
> When `/blog_categories/2` is rendered I am trying to have it show the
>   name of the subcategory (**"Good"** in this case) followed by its
>   parent category (**"News"** in this case).
>
> The desired result is to be a header stating **"Good News"**

`BlogCategory` **Model:**

```
class BlogCategory < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts

  # This is called a self referential relation. This is where records in a table may point to other records in the same table.
  has_many :sub_categories, class_name: "BlogCategory", foreign_key: :parent_id

  # This is a scope to load the top level categories and eager-load their posts, subcategories, and the subcategories' posts too.
  scope :top_level, -> { where(parent_id: nil).includes :posts, sub_categories: :posts }
end
```

`Blog_categories` **controller:**

```
class BlogCategoriesController < ApplicationController

def index
  @categories = BlogCategory.top_level.includes(sub_categories: :posts)
  @category = BlogCategory.find_by_id(params[:id])
  unless @category.nil? # Allows for categories to have nothing in them, eliminating the NoMethodError
    @sub_category = @category.sub_categories.first
    @posts = @subcategory.posts
  end
  @all_posts = Post.all
end

def show
  @category = BlogCategory.find_by_id(params[:id])
  @sub_category = @category.sub_categories
  @posts = @category.posts
end

private

  def cat_params
    params.require(:blog_category).permit(:name, :parent_id, :sub_category)
  end

end
```

My **Show View**:

```
<% BlogCategory.top_level do |category| %>
  <% category.sub_categories do |sub_category| %>
    <h2 class="center p-space blog-h2"><%= sub_category.name %> <%= category.name %></h2>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I've tried a few combinations of `do` statements but I really cant crack this problem. I would love some help in figuring this one out, thanks!

If this helps, I've had some success with `<%= @category.name %>` but it only shows the sub_category's name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you need to display current category name + current category subcategories names. Try to adapt this example to your needs:

```
# controller
def show
  @category = BlogCategory.find(params[:id])
  if @category.present?
    @sub_cat_names = @category.sub_categories.map(&:name)
    @posts         = @category.posts
  end
end

# view
<% if @category.present? %>
  <h2>Current category:</h2> <%= @category.name %>
  <h3>Sub categories:</h3> <%= @sub_cat_names.join(', ') %>
<% end %>
```

---

**UPDATE**

I don't understand why do you need `@category` and `@sub_category` variables in `show` action if you don't use them in the view. In accordance with your latest additions, the solution can look like this:

```
# model
class BlogCategory < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts
  has_many :sub_categories, class_name: 'BlogCategory', foreign_key: :parent_id

  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'BlogCategory'

  scope :top_level, -> { where(parent_id: nil).includes :posts, sub_categories: :posts }
end

# controller
def show
  @sub_category = BlogCategory.find(params[:id])
  @category     = @sub_category.parent
end

# view
<h2 class="center p-space blog-h2">
  <%= "#{@sub_category.name} #{@category.name}" %>
</h2>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, but this one actually just lists every single subcategory and category in a list. My objective is that when on the URL: `/blog_categories/6` for example, it will show the subcategory followed by the category it belongs to.

Comment: I think it's close but this one actually lists every value for every column. (its even more information) I don't know why though, it's pulling stuff that's not even called for in the `.erb`.

Comment: @Jake sorry, you don't need to use an equal sign, my mistake. Please, check my code again. It should work fine, I've just checked the similar example in my app. And please make some screenshot of what you need, it is hard to imagine your expected result.

Comment: I've tried the code you just updated and it doesn't load anything at all. Would this be a problem I may be having in my controller? This code is in the `show` view

Comment: Hey, I realized that this code does work when loading the main category with `parent_id` of `NULL` but it just doesn't show the code when it's a `sub_category` that's being rendered. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: @Jake again - I'm not sure if I correctly understand what you need. So try updated code and if something wrong please, update your question with more details and example of the expected result.

Comment: Zanadto, I'm sorry for so much confusion, I thank you for sticking with me on this and I have updated the code with what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks, the only thing it broke (I then fixed) was the posts weren't loading. I found the solution to this to be `@cat = BlogCategory.friendly.find(params[:id])` `@posts = @cat.posts` Place this into your answer to help others if they come across this.

Comment: I also came across another issue where It would not work for top_level. I used an `if / else` statement in my view (along with the code in my previous comment). `<% if BlogCategory.top_level %> <h2 class="center p-space blog-h2"><%= "All #{@cat.name}" %></h2> <% else %> <h2 class="center p-space blog-h2"><%= "#{@sub_category.name} #{@category.name}" %></h2> <% end %>` But this just uses `<%= "All #{@cat.name}" %>` on everything, even if it's a `sub_category`. Any thoughts on getting around this?